# Xcode - how to make a level unlock system?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, development-environment, viewdidload

Hey guys I was just wondering how i could do this in Xcode. Any help would be appreciated

I would like to begin my level (that is already made) and then use the viewdidload (in my level view) to change a button in my level selector (separate view and xib to the level selector) this button needs to be changed into a round rect button that features a certain text that in this case will need to be "Level1". This button will need to be changed from a custom button which currently has a image of a Padlock to inform the user that the level is currently locked. Once that has been done I need to save the changes as a game default so that once the app has been closed it does not loose what levels you have unlocked

any help will be appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

well buttonType  is a readonly property which can be set at the time of initialize as

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

the way to achieve what you want is just make two buttons and on the requirement just show or hide the buttons as

```
[btn1 setHidden:YES];
[btn2 setHidden:NO];
```

EDIT: For this purpose of saving values without loosing there are lot of options .The easier one is the `NSUserDefaluts` Where you can store a value to a key string and retrieve back

- [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
- [Tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/nsuserdefaults_iphone-sdk/)

For changing the value from 2nd VC to 1st you have to implement delegate method on the 2nd VC to trigger an action in the 1st VC

[Tutorial on Delegation](http://www.roostersoftstudios.com/2011/04/12/simple-delegate-tutorial-for-ios-development/)

Comment: Thanks it will help a bit but I appreciate it

Comment: Edited my answer .Check it

Comment: I'm sorry I'm quite new to this but how can I change the button from a different view controller  because the level and the level selector are on different pages

Comment: added to the answer.Check it

Comment: Thanks mate you have really helped me out I will try it out in a min and tell you if it works

Comment: Im sorry but I'm stupid and I'm still not understanding

Comment: Im stuck on the delicate method because in the example he uses a text field and number enter

Comment: i answered the other question of how to implemet the delegate.hope it helps